# What is the present relevance

Tags: present-perfect

> However, work continued and today the major structural restoration is virtually complete. The building **has been painted** in a stone colour (as it was in 1827) to recreate as true a likeness as possible to the appearance of Bath stone blocks.

What is the present relevance to justify present perfect  for painted is it today and to emphasize the comparaison withe original in 1827

https://brightonmuseums.org.uk/royalpavilion/history/conservation-and-restoration/

Answer (score 4):

It's a little unclear what you are asking, but I'm going to assume you want to know why the writer chose:

> The building **has been painted**

rather than

> The building **is painted**

The use of the present perfect relates to the previous sentence, which talks about the recent completion of some significant amount of work.  It implies that the painting of the blocks *is part of that reconstruction process*, rather than a separate and possibly unrelated feature.

(Edit)  Let me give an example of the difference in nuance between the present perfect and simple present in a similar context:

> The renovation of the historic courthouse is almost complete.  The two columns of the facade replaced after the fire **have been painted** to match the other six columns, which **are painted** a distinctive maroon.

We say the new columns "have been painted" to relate this action to the renovation mentioned in the previous sentence.  Meanwhile we say the existing columns "are painted" to indicate they are *not* part of the renovation.

Comment: Could it be also because the restoration is not completely  fully finished that the writer choose present perfect

Comment: @user5577  Based on the context, that's not likely.  The previous sentence says "virtually complete".

Comment: In your sample para, what justification is there for: "have been painted" and then, which "are painted"? The verbs could both be SP or PP but not one SP and one PP. That simply does not read well.  I disagree completely with that analysis.

Answer (score -3):

**ONE POSSIBILITY**
**If you have a date**, use simple past. Here, the passive.

**The building was painted in 1827**. [a one-off action that is finished]
versus
**The building has been painted several times in two centuries**. [no particular dates given, just in the past.]

**SECOND POSSIBILITY**

**The building has been painted a stone color (*to look as it did in 1827*)**

You can't use "as it was in 1827" because that is ambiguous and makes the verb paint sound as if it is in the wrong tense.

The present perfect can be used because no date for the painting is given and the 1827 date issue is clarified by saying: to look as it did in 1827).

Please google: Historical restorations + to look exactly as it did in [year or time or etc] or historical restorations + to look as it did in [year etc.]

Comment: **The building has been painted** several times in two centuries, exactly as **it was painted in 1827**.

Comment: Not exactly as it was painted. The building has been painted several times in two centuries **to look exactly as it did in 1827**. Look. Any good English language editor will confirm what I have said. You can check historical home restorations. They will all say: to look exactly as it did in [some year]. Take a look: https://www.google.com/search?q=historical+restorations+%2B%22+to+look+exactly+as+it+did+in%22&oq=historical+restorations+%2B%22+to+look+exactly+as+it+did+in%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.28134j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8